# Snowflake caching not working with Snowpark Python 1.0

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake is caching already executed queries, such that subsequent executions of the same query will finish much faster. As far as I know, this only works if the query is exactely the same.

In my app (a interactive dashboard which uses Snowpark-Python 1.0 to fire snowflake queries), this caching does not seem to work. Each time the (same snowpark) query is fired, snowflake does run the query again:
[image]

Depending on whether the warehouse cache is active are not (blue vs green bar), the execution time is several 100ms up to 2s. **The result is not read from the cache.**

I think the cause is that the generated SQL does contain random components (column and table names suffixes) which are different for each query:

[image]

How can I make use of the snowflake cache using Snowpark-generated queries?

Comment: specifying `lsuffix` and `rsuffix` in the join eleminates the random suffixes in the column names, but the random suffix in the TEMP_TABLE remain

Comment: Have you tried running queries that take at least a few minutes? 2 sec is really not a lot. One could run  `select 1` and still see execution time anywhere between 20 ms to 50 ms

Comment: @RaphaelRoth This has been reported internally in Snowflake as well and we are currently investigating for a possible solution.

Comment: @Sergiu thanks I know that it was reported (i reported it to snowflake) :)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth The fix is in Snowpark 1.2.0 release which came out last week.